# What's the smarter option: Ruby logic or SQL function?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, optimization, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-postgresql

I needed to write a method that always returns an integer value. If the record is non-existent, the method returns 0

I have a unique index on the columns being queried and came up with two solutions:

```
# Option a) Ruby logic
def some_method id
  result = Model.some_scope.find(:first,
                                  conditions: { foo_id: id },
                                  select: :int_value)

  # Return 0 if record does not exist:
  ( result.nil? ? 0 : result.int_value )
end


# Option b) Allow Postgres to do the work
def some_method id
  # sum() returns 0 if the record wasn't found
  Model.some_scope.where(foo_id: id).sum(:int_value)
end
```

Because of the unique index, both methods return the same value.

Is there any reason one solution is better than the other, aside from brevity?

My inclination is to choose the solution based on server resources, i.e. minimizing database server load by giving the job to Ruby.

---

Running Ruby 1.9.3 and Postgres 9.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the (possibly more expensive) aggregate function `sum()`.
Use SQL-[`COALESCE()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) for that.

`COALESCE` is probably the cheapest way. But the cost is so tiny, it does not matter either way.

Comment: Agreed, there's just no meaningful difference in load when you're dealing with work at this scale. The overhead of the query setup and return is vastly greater than any other part of this. If you're going to worry about performance, think about aggregating the work at a higher level so you can ask the database for a large set of results at once.